# Is there any way to compare two files and generate output with only differences in field level using datastage?

Tags: datastage

I have two files, 
File A
id,name,address,phone
01,abc,cde,345
02,efg,ghi,654

File B
id,name,address,phone
01,abc,edc,231
02,abc,ghi,789

Output file will have the data in below format if there is difference in records for each field.
Output File
id,fields,value from File A,value from File B
01,address,cde,edc
01,phone,345,231
02,name,efg,abc
02,phone,654,789

output shouldn't have 01,name,abc,abc because it is matching from both file.key column will be id.
Any design based on dastage will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note for future posts to improve your formatting as your examples are really hard to read - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is - I suggest to check out the [Change_Capture stage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/c_deeref_Change_Capture_Stage.html).
Alternatively the [Difference stage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/c_deeref_Difference_Stage.html) might also be an option

Both stages will return information if a row from the one file compared to the other is a Copy, Delete, Insert or Edit. You can filter that to just return what you are interested in.

The decision on which stage is suited best depends on which information to return the "before" or "after" values (which again depends how you define the file A and file B) 
the documentation will show some examples.